# Passing data from dynamic components as an object to parent component

Tags: vue.js

I have created a form that dynamically renders a group of inputs so I can add and remove that group of inputs depending on how many the end-user needs.

Like this:

[image]

I render the "item" inputs using dynamic components:

```
<component v-for="itemRow in itemRows" :is="itemRow"></component>
```

The data for the parent looks like this:

```
components: {
  ItemRow
},
data() {
  return {
    retailer: "",
    items: [],
    itemRows: ['ItemRow','ItemRow', 'ItemRow'],
    date: new Date(),
  }
}
```

And the child component:

```
data() {
  return {
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    count: 0
}
```

So what I want to do is to make an object of the child data and pass that object to the items array in the parent. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) an event from the child.

In the parent subscribe to that event

```
<component v-for="itemRow in itemRows" :is="itemRow" @onChange="updateRow"></component>
```

You'll also need to pass the index to the child so the parent knows from which element it's receiving the event

```
<component v-for="(itemRow, index) in itemRows" :is="itemRow" :index="index" @onChange="updateRow"></component>
```

This means that you need to define a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) on the child component(s).

Remember to update the array using [Vue.set/this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), otherwise you're array won't be reactive.

Comment: From when do I emit in the child? Using watch to see when something changes in the data properties?

Comment: This depends on your use case. You can either watch the data or register to an onchange event on the input fields and fire it from that handler. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: Thank you so much!